# Script to install Flash Player through postinst

Tags: bash

I have created a debian package. I need to check for the Adobe Flash Player while installing this .deb. If flash player is not installed then i need to install it also. On browsing i got to know that postinst file can be used for this purpose. 
The postinst file is

```
#!/bin/bash

echo “Stopping any Firefox that might be running”
sudo killall -9 firefox

echo “Removing any other flash plugin previously installed:”
sudo apt-get remove -y –purge flashplugin-nonfree gnash gnash-common mozilla-plugin-gnash swfdec-mozilla libflashsupport nspluginwrapper
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -f ~/.mozilla/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/*flash*
sudo rm -rfd /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper

echo “Installing Flash Player 10″
#cd ~
sudo cp /home/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/

echo “Linking the libraries so Firefox and apps depending on XULRunner.”
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins/

# now doing some cleaning up:
sudo rm -rf libflashplayer.so
sudo rm -rf libflashplayer-10.0.32.18.linux-x86_64.so.tar.gz
```

But nothing is happening. 
Can anyone help me to write the script to install flash player through script?

Comment: Why not list the flash plugin as a dependency of the package, using debian/control?

Comment: Is there any error message you can show us?

Comment: The signal `-9` (`SIGKILL`) should only be used as a last resort since it can't be caught and so the program doesn't have a chance to exit gracefully. Try `#!/bin/bash -x` to get a trace and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got your `$HOME` path wrong:

```
sudo cp /home/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

did you mean:

```
sudo cp $HOME/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actual code was echo “Installing Flash Player 10″ cd ~ wget download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/… tar zxvf libflashplayer-10.0.42.34.linux-x86_64.so.tar.gz sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/ But i have kept libflashplayer.so in /home directory